# vue is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I have node version v10.24.1 and npm 6.14.2

but when I try to run command npm install -g @vue/cli or specifics by version display this error:

Any idea?
thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `vue --version` instead.

Comment: @Neha Soni show the same error also when i run command
vue --version

Comment: Install node v16 and follow the following: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application